# Problem with an object pooling mechanism, Queue containing the pool can't be static because static variables aren't inherited

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up an object pooling mechanism in unity, basically how it works is:
You have a base abstract class called "Poolable", with a static queue containing objects in it (In this case GameObjects), there's a class called Projectile which inherits from Poolable as that's what i currently want to be pooled. It further extends to a Bullet class which inherits from Projectile, but the problem is, if i had an Arrow class which inherits from Projectile, it would use the same pool because the pool is static inside Poolable. Does anyone know a way i could tackle this issue?

I thought about making it non-static, but then the objects wouldn't know about the pool, they'd know about their own pool. Same with interfaces but they don't accept variables which aren't properties
The only current fix i see is adding it to each script that i use a pool on, but that then defeats the whole purpose of inheritance as i was trying to make a polymorphic-like structure where you'd have multiple poolables, multiple projectiles, maybe multiple bullets/arrows?

```
public abstract class Poolable : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected static Queue<GameObject> objPool = new Queue<GameObject>(); // doesn't work because every poolable object will use this pool only
    [SerializeField] protected GameObject prefab;

    public GameObject Get()
    {
        if(objPool.Count == 0)
        {
            AddObjects();
        }

        return objPool.Dequeue();
    }

    protected void ReturnToPool(GameObject retObj)
    {
        objPool.Enqueue(retObj);
        retObj.SetActive(false);
    }

    AddObjects()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If your class is generic - `Poolable<Arrow>`, `Poolable<Bullet>`, etc., then the static members will be unique to each of those types.

Comment: @Scott: it's true that a generic type would have a different concrete field for each type parameter used for that type. But, it doesn't address the polymorphic aspect. I.e. since `Arrow` inherits `Projectile`, the base class would be `Poolable<Projectile>`, not `Poolable<Arrow>`, defeating the point of a type-specific field. The `Projectile` pool would still wind up being shared by e.g. `Arrow` and `Bullet`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really understand your code example. You have a static pool, but then your `Get()` method is non-static. So you already have an object of the desired type in hand when you call it. What is the point of that? It would be helpful to have a more realistic illustration of how you would retrieve new objects. It seems more likely you'd have a static accessor somewhere, and thus would need some means of specifying the type. If that's the case, I'd think a simple dictionary of pools, where the type is the key, would work fine. A generic method could be used to specific the type.

Comment: But that's just an idea, and whether that would work in your case depends on the broader picture, which you haven't shared. Please elaborate on your question so that it's more clear, more constrained, and less broad.

Comment: Another question is what you hope to gain by making the pooling code itself polymorphic. This relates to the point above, i.e. _"you already have an object of the desired type"_. There are a number of examples of how to do object pooling in Unity3d, and generally they organize the pools according to the prefab that the objects are based on. Then for example you could declare these fields in a scene, with a designated prefab for each, and just access the appropriate named pool any time you need an object based on that prefab. Is there some reason that approach doesn't work for you?

Comment: The Get method was supposed to be static, that was my bad yeah.
The pooling code being inheritable would allow me to create other classes that would be pooled, and thus creating a "polymorphic-like" structure;
Example: an arrow, a flaming arrow, bullets, types of bullets
A flaming arrow would inherit from the normal arrow, which inherits from projectile, which inherits from poolable. See the chain?
The same would go for bullets, but they'd inherit from the bullet class
Solution below works perfectly though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you need your object pool to be homogeneous. This means your pool contains only one type of object. For example, you don't want `arrow` and `bullet` to share the same pool even if they are all `projectiles`. We don't have c++'s `decltype` in c#, so if you want your object to have it's non-static member function `ReturnToPool`, you have to defer type evaluation to run-time (using a type dictionary). Here is the code that would possibly satisfy your need:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public abstract class Poolable : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Queue<Component>> objPool
        = new Dictionary<Type, Queue<Component>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Get an object from the pool; If fails, use the alternative method to create one
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="alternativeCreate"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Get<T>(Func<T> alternativeCreate) where T : Poolable
    {
        if (objPool.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var queue) && queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var ret = queue.Dequeue() as T;
            ret.Reactive();
            return ret;
        }
        return alternativeCreate();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the object to the pool
    /// </summary>
    public void ReturnToPool()
    {
        if (this.Reset())
        {
            var type = this.GetType();
            Queue<Component> queue;
            if (objPool.TryGetValue(type, out queue))
            {
                queue.Enqueue(this);
            }
            else
            {
                queue = new Queue<Component>();
                queue.Enqueue(this);
                objPool.Add(type, queue);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reset the object so it is ready to go into the object pool
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>whether the reset is successful.</returns>
    protected virtual bool Reset()
    {
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reactive the object as it goes out of the object pool
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void Reactivate()
    {
        this.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you rather simply make the prefabs not of type `GameObject` but of the type you actually want you could a `Queue<Component>` and get rid of the `GetComponent` call.

Comment: @derHugo You're correct, a type cast is faster than a `GetComponent` call. Have edited the answer.

Comment: You're a savior i don't think i would have come up with this for a pretty long time...at least not with my knowledge
Thanks!

Comment: The way it works is by creating a queue and adding them onto the dictionary, right? So it doesn't directly change how and what classes inheriting from poolable get, it just creates a queue and adds it to the static dictionary the first time you try to get an item from it? And it works because you can pass in types (example, flaming arrow, bullet, etc), so it finds the queue via the type?

Comment: @aron Yes to both questions. Type metadata is always at your service when you are using C#! You can always know what an object really is by querying its type.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into the Singleton Pattern. It's hard to suggest a suitable implementation for what you need because I don't know what you want to do with it, but basically, you can add something like this to your class:

```
private static Poolable _instance;
private static object _instanceLock = new Object();
public static Poolable Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            lock (_instanceLock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    this._instance = [Whatever way you instantiate it];
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }

}
```

Afterward, either make the constructor private/protected and make sure you always get your instance with `Poolable.Instance`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well a singleton could work...in a way
But my problem is that i want the static queue to be "inherited" for the projectile class, then for each bullet/arrow, so that they have separate static queue's, or in this case pools
Imagine an arrow, and a bullet class which both have the same methods from poolable, but they both also have their own static Queue<GameObjects>, that's what i want to achieve, hopefully without copying the code every time i make a new type of the "projectile" class so that i can keep the inheritance

Comment: I don't see how this helps original problem of having one instance when OP wanted instance per class... Also @aron please make sure to read https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton and ignore code in this answer if you do need singleton.

Comment: Hm..didn't know there was this much to singletons! Not sure i need one, but thanks for the link anyway! It'll help for sure in another area

Comment: @aron This answer shows the idea behind the singleton, but making the `Poolable` class generic would also be a step in the right direction, but be careful now to be "too specific" when you request/create the singleton; if for example, you have `Bullet`, `Arrow` and `FireArrow` (that inherits from `Arrow`) you might not want a `Poolable<FireArrow>` ever, and instead use `Poolable<Arrow>` for both `Arrow` and `FireArrow`.

Comment: When you define a class, you can choose whether you create one instance and reuse it or create multiple instances. For that reason I can't see the benefit of writing a class as a singleton in most cases. It forces you do to something you already had the ability to do. It takes away a choice and in return makes unit testing more difficult.